# How do I assign shooting to a specific key?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm very new to coding and Unity. I want to make it so that my character shoots a shuriken prefab when the S key is pressed down.

The issue is that I cannot get the shuriken to appear when I press a key. When I just have the ShurikenLeft and ShurikenRight prefabs in the hierarchy, they will still shoot in the right direction and disappear after 3 seconds which is what I want. I just can't map it to a specific key so that it appears when I press it down.

I used this guide to make this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1QOsUrXWMWY
The guy says that the shoot button is assigned to CTRL by default but it still doesn't work when I click that. I've gone to Edit > Project settings > Input and changed Fire1 to Throw1 so that also isn't the problem.

Here is all of my code:

ShurikenScript:

```
        public class ShurikenScript : MonoBehaviour {

        public float velX = 10f;
        float velY = 0f;
        Rigidbody2D rb;
        // Use this for initialization
        void Start () {
            rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        }
    
        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update () {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(velX, velY);
            Destroy(gameObject, 3f);
        }
    }
```

PlayerMovement:

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Security.Cryptography;
    using System.Threading;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {

        float velX;
        float velY;
        bool facingRight = true;

        public GameObject ShurikenRight, ShurikenLeft;
        Vector2 ShurikenPos;
        public float throwRate = 0.5f;
        float nextThrow = 0f;

        Rigidbody2D rb;

        // Use this for initialization
        void Start() {
            rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
            rb.freezeRotation = true;
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update() {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
            {
                rb.AddForce(new Vector3(1, 0), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            }
            else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
            {
                rb.AddForce(new Vector3(-1, 0), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            }
            else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
            {
                rb.AddForce(new Vector3(0, 2), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
                Debug.Log("Jump");
            }
            else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
            {
                rb.AddForce(new Vector3(0, -3), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
                Debug.Log("Jump");
            }



            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Throw1") && Time.time > nextThrow)
            {
                nextThrow = Time.time + throwRate;
                Throw();
            }
        }

        void Throw()
        {
            ShurikenPos = transform.position;
            if (facingRight)
            {
                ShurikenPos += new Vector2(+2.2f, 3.355f);
                Instantiate(ShurikenRight, ShurikenPos, Quaternion.identity);
            }


            else
            {
                ShurikenPos += new Vector2(2.2f, 3.355f);
                Instantiate(ShurikenLeft, ShurikenPos, Quaternion.identity);
            }
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you call it “Throw1” as you said you did or “Throw 1” as your code uses

Comment: Do you get any messages on your console? I recommend putting a Debug.Log in your if statement where you call the Throw() function and see if you can enter inside or not. It might not be an issue regarding the key you use.

Comment: I would say its a "throw1" matter, but it works when is not a prefab, so it should be good, Just be sure you have your prefab linked at the inspector. The code seems right.

Comment: Guys im so dumb... I didn't notice that in Input settings there are 2 Fire1's so I only changed the second one to Throw1 LMAO, just edited the second one too and it worked so thank u guys for helping me realize that